# Mongoose can't connect to default collection using user/password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I added authentication to mongo, now I can't use mongooose to connect to a default collection.

```
import { Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
let mongoose = new Mongoose();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://root:role@server.com/collectionName");
```

This would connect and create the collectionName on the fly. Now I get a connection error and the only way to fix this is to remove the default collection from the connectionString.

I create a mongo user with root role this way.

---Mongo--

```
> use admin;
> db.auth('admin','password')
> db.createUser({user: "root", pwd: "role", roles: ["root"]})
```

Is there anything I seem to be doing wrong? Mongo v.3.4.5

Comment: Did you [enable authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control) on the `mongod` instance? Simply adding users does not turn authentication on. You need to restart the instance in authenticated mode.

Comment: Yes I have, I'm running Mongo in a docker container, I used the --auth flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `collectionName` you mentioned is database name.

As my understanding, you are creating username+password for db `admin`.
Now if you want to create user/password for your `dbName` you need to use this:

```
use dbName
db.createUser({ user: "root", pwd: "root",
roles: [{ role:"dbOwner",db: "dbName" } ] })
```

Of course, you can use another role which you want

Comment: Just a moment let me try.

Comment: Didn't work >> errmsg: 'Authentication failed.', code: 18, codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'

Comment: You need to use database you want to create user.
`use databaseName`, i will edit my answer